# Correct way to use two Views on top of each other

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I want an application that uses Samsung S Pen as input, and draws something with OpenGL ES.
Basicly i need two views (both inherited from android.view.SurfaceView)

- `GLSurfaceView`
- `SpenSurfaceView`

The `SpenSurfaceView` should be on top, to catch all the input gesture.
The `GLSurfaceView` must be visible too. I might need to change visibility of the `SpenSurfaceView` (probably with the .setAlpha(float) method )

What is the most common way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<FrameLayout>
  <GlSurfaceView ... />
  <SpenSurfaceView ... />
</FrameLayout>
```

or, if you can't use resources and the layout inflater:

```
FrameLayout fl = // get or find frame layout
fl.addChild(yourGlSurfaceView);
fl.addChild(yourSpenSurfaceView);
```

The greater question is, can you not just draw to the SpenSurfaceView's surface directly?  Then you don't need the second GlSurfaceView.

Comment: I use 3D grapics, so it would be hard to implement the drawing directly to the SpenSurfaceView. I am not sure if the GlSurfaceView does not cut out a part of the display, and do the rendering all by itself. I have to run some tests, and I will update the post ASAP.

Comment: First problem is that I cant use XML layout. When I declare the SpenSurfaceView in XML, the error is: Error inflating class com.samsung.android.sdk.pen.engine.SpenSurfaceView

Comment: @AndrásKovács does the error explicitly prevent you from inflating from xml, or are you perhaps doing something wrong?  I would be surprised if Samsung would not allow you to inflate an SpenSurfaceView via xml.

Comment: Its a runtime error. But all the Samsung tutorial adds it on the Java side, and that worked for me too.